# Continuity: multiple Elizabeths in the same reality?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

Warning: There Be Spoilers Ahead

> In the [Bioshock Infinite Timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLmmm.jpg), and on multiple recordings, it is revealed, that during the events taking place after the second tear-jump (at which the Vox revolted), Elizabeth was moved to Comstock House, so DeWitt couldn't get to her. This means that in the reality taking place after the second jump, and before "Old Elizabeth" brings DeWitt to the future, there should be 2 Elizabeths in the same reality.

[This brings up a number of questions](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FridgeLogic):

- Why was Songbird looking for Elizabeth in the first place, when she's locked up safely?
- Why is Comstock telling the party that "you team up with the false prophet", when *that didn't happened*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Songbird is never really explained, other than he has a "connection to the girl". It seems reasonable to assume that this would extend to *all* Elizabeths. If that's the case, it's simple -- Songbird senses an Elizabeth that is not in the Comstock House, and goes looking for her (and being Songbird, is unable to communicate that it senses two).

As to your second question, do you have a specific example? I'm not quite sure what bit you're referring to. In all likelyhood, though, you can blame the Tears; if Comstock saw Elizabeth being "led astray" through a Tear, and Booker was already dead, the simplest answer was that Booker wasn't the false prophet he saw (since he was looking into the future, he saw alternate-reality Booker [the player].)

Being a Booker himself, is it really that much of a stretch for Comstock to expect to find a 3rd?